# Unable to send object in Express response

Tags: javascript, rest, express

I'm trying to send all the data from my database back using res.send, but it's throwing me an error. On my frontend, I'm calling the endpoint `select` and trying to return all rows and data within the database.

```
app.get('/select', function (req, res) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM Contracts', function (err, rows, fields) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var row = rows[i];
      res.send(row);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Try not wrapping your response in a for loop. Accumulate all the rows into one object and send it one time.

Comment: Why don't you just send the whole `rows` array?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `res.write` instead of `res.send` as the latter terminates the function (nothing after the first use of `res.send` is executed)

```
app.get('/select', function (req, res) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM Contracts', function (err, rows, fields) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var row = rows[i];
      res.write(row);
    }
    res.end(); //this finally sends the response
  })
});
```

Or if you want to use `res.send` send the whole `rows` array:

```
app.get('/select', function (req, res) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM Contracts', function (err, rows, fields) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }

    res.send(rows);
  })
});
```

Comment: Where does `res.write` write to though? I tried both and I keep getting this error. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: It writes to an anonymous object that is sent to the user with res.end, in what line does that error occur?

Comment: It throws the error in an unrelated module. `node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80` the error being throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors